# Groupby dataframe to get not null elements from each group member

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, fillna

I have a dataframe where in some cases a case has its records in more than one row, with nulls in some rows as so:

```
    date_rounded          1  2        3     4     5
0   2020-04-01 00:05:00 0.0  NaN     NaN    NaN   NaN   
1   2020-04-01 00:05:00 NaN  1.0     44.0   44.0  46.454    
2   2020-04-01 00:05:00 NaN  NaN     NaN    NaN   NaN
```

I want to have only one row with the filled data, so far I have:

```
df.groupby(['date_rounded']).apply(lambda df0: df0.fillna(method='ffill').fillna(method='bfill').drop_duplicates())
```

this works, but it is slow, any better ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `groupby` and `first`:

```
df.groupby("date_rounded").first()

                       1    2     3     4       5
date_rounded                                     
2020-04-01 00:05:00  0.0  1.0  44.0  44.0  46.454
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to fill within each group, you can use `groupby().apply` and `bfill`:

```
df.groupby('date_rounded', as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.bfill().iloc[0])
```

Output:

```
0         date_rounded    1    2     3     4       5
0  2020-04-01 00:05:00  0.0  1.0  44.0  44.0  46.454
```